# The <ul> Doesn't move inside to the footer even though it is?

Tags: html, css

The  list doesn't move inside the footer even though it is inside the
 tag.

I Tried looking into another useful site and some 
of the threads here in SO but no luck....

I also tried putting float:left, etc...

[image: Dislocated Navbar]

HTML:

```
  <footer>
                  <!-- <section class="f-sec1"> -->
                       <!-- <h5>CAD | Tech Website&copy;</h5> -->
                       <ul class="f-li">
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                  </ul>

                        <br>



                  </section>
             </footer>
```

CSS:

```
   footer {
       background: #444;
   }

   /* First Section */

   .f-sec1 h5 {
       color: #FFFFFF;
   }

   .h-sec {
       font: 22px Arial, Helvetica;
   }

   .sec {
       font: 9px, Arial, Helvetica;
   }

   .fl-li {
       list-style-type: none;
   }
   .f-li li a {
       color: #000000;
       float: right;
   }

   .f-li .current {
       color: #A9A9A9;
       text-decoration: underline;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Added clearfix, and it worked:

```
<footer class="clearfix">
  <!-- <section class="f-sec1"> -->
  <!-- <h5>CAD | Tech Website&copy;</h5> -->
  <ul class="f-li">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when you close the footer instead of the section.

```css
footer {
  background: #444;
}


/* First Section */

.f-sec1 h5 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.h-sec {
  font: 22px Arial, Helvetica;
}

.sec {
  font: 9px, Arial, Helvetica;
}

.f-li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.f-li li a {
  color: #000000;
  float: right;
}

.f-li .current {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <!-- <section class="f-sec1"> -->
  <!-- <h5>CAD | Tech Website&copy;</h5> -->
  <ul class="f-li">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: It has ending tag of footer (forgot to include in the thread) but still like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the footer tag.

```
<footer>
     <!-- <h5>CAD | Tech Website&copy;</h5> -->
     <ul class="f-li">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
     </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: It has ending tag of footer (forgot to include in the thread).